# Layout issues for vertical tab while using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a vertical tab menu using bootstrap. I would like to get a background for the tabs so that it would differentiate from the tab content on the right. When I try to use the background color for nav the tabs look inconsistent with the nav background color

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="TABBEDLOCATEPANEL" ng-show="locate.toggleCheck()" class="container">
  <div id=locatePanel class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3">
      <div class="tabs-left">
        <ul id=locateTabs class="nav form-tabs nav-pills nav-stacked">
      <li class="active" title="Locate By Address"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#locateTab1" target='_self'><img src="images/Address.png" height="30" width="30"></img></a></li>
      <li title="Locate By Existing Record"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#locateTab2" target='_self'><img src="images/entity.png" height="30" width="30"></img></a></li>
      <li title="Locate By Coordinate"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#locateTab3" target='_self'><img src="images/coordinator.png" height="30" width="30"></img></a></li>
      <li title="Geography" ng-show="locate.getJSON().geographyTab" ng-click="locate.showGeographyData();"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#locateTab4" target='_self'><img src="images/geography.png" height="30" width="30"></img></a></li>
      <li title="Results" id="ltab5" ng-show="locate.resultsTab"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#locateTab5" target='_self'><img src="images/Result.png" height="30" width="30"></img></a></li>
  </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
         <div id="locateTab1" class="tab-pane active">
    <table id=locateAddress style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 5px;">
     <div class="field-container">
                 <input type='text' class="field" name=locatebyaddress_address ng-model="locate.locatebyaddress_address" required placeholder="Address"  init-from-form>
     <label class="floating-label">Address:</label>
           <div class="field-underline"></div>
        </div>
         <div class="field-container">
                 <input type='text' class="field" name=locatebyaddress_city ng-model="locate.locatebyaddress_city" required placeholder="City" init-from-form>
     <label class="floating-label">City:</label>
           <div class="field-underline"></div>
        </div>
         <div class="field-container">
                 <input type='text' class="field" name=locatebyaddress_state ng-model="locate.locatebyaddress_state" required placeholder="State"  init-from-form>
     <label class="floating-label">State:</label>
           <div class="field-underline"></div>
        </div>
         <div class="field-container">
                 <input type='text' class="field" name=locatebyaddress_zip ng-model="locate.locatebyaddress_zip" required placeholder="Zip" init-from-form>
     <label class="floating-label">Zip:</label>
           <div class="field-underline"></div>
        </div>
         <div class="field-container">
                 <input type='text' class="field" name=locatebyaddress_longitude disabled=disabled ng-model="locate.locatebyaddress_longitude" required placeholder="Longitude"  init-from-form>
     <label class="floating-label">Longitude:</label>
           <div class="field-underline"></div>
        </div>
         <div class="field-container">
                 <input type='text' class="field" name=locatebyaddress_latitude disabled=disabled ng-model="locate.locatebyaddress_latitude" required placeholder="Latitude"  init-from-form>
     <label class="floating-label">Latitude:</label>
           <div class="field-underline"></div>
        </div>
     
    </table>
    <br>
    <input type=submit value=Find id=locateByAddress ng-click="locate.locateByAddress();"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type=button ng-click="locate.zoomToLocation();" ng-disabled="locate.entityDisabledCheck" ng-class="{'disabledButton':locate.isDisabledActive}" value="Zoom" id=zoomtolocation></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type=reset value=Cancel ng-click="locate.destroyLocatePanel();" id=cancelLocate></input>
   </div>
   <div id="locateTab2" class="tab-pane">
    <table id=locateRecord style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 5px;">
     <tr>
      <td>Entity Type</td>
      <td>
       <select id=locateEntityType ng-change="locate.entityChanged();"  ng-model="locate.entityType">
        <option></option>
        <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in locate.getJSON().dropdown" value="{{key}}">{{ value }}</option>
       </select> 
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td>Record Number</td><td><input id=recordNumberExistingRecord ng-model="locate.recordNumber" type=text name=recordNumber></td></tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <input type=submit value=Find id=locateByExistingRecord ng-click="locate.getLocationByEntity();"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type=button ng-click="locate.zoomToLocation();" ng-disabled="locate.entityDisabledCheck" ng-class="{'disabledButton':locate.isDisabledActive}" value="Zoom" id=zoomtolocation></input>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=reset value=Cancel ng-click="locate.destroyLocatePanel();" id=cancelLocate></input>
   </div>
   <div id="locateTab3" class="tab-pane">
    <table id=locateCoordinates style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 5px;">
     <tr><td>Longitude</td><td><input type=text ng-model=locate.locateByCoordinatelongitude></td></tr>
     <tr><td>Latitude</td><td><input type=text ng-model=locate.locateByCoordinatelatitude></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td><td><input type=button ng-click="locate.pickCoordinate();" id=coordinatePick name=locatePick value=PICK></td></tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <input type=submit value=Find id=locateByCoordinate ng-click="locate.locateByCoordinate();"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type=button ng-click="locate.zoomToLocation();" ng-disabled="locate.entityDisabledCheck" ng-class="{'disabledButton':locate.isDisabledActive}" value="Zoom" id=zoomtolocation></input>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=reset value=Cancel ng-click="locate.destroyLocatePanel();" id=cancelLocate></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type=button ng-click="locate.streetView();" ng-show="locate.streetViewCheck" value="Street View" id=streetView></input>
   </div>
   <div id="locateTab4" class="tab-pane" ng-show="locate.getJSON().geographyTab">
    <div ng-html-compile="locate.getGeographyHTML()" | trust></div>
   </div>
   <div id="locateTab5" class="tab-pane" ng-show="locate.resultsTab">
    <ul class="listAddress">
     <li ng-repeat="list in locate.addressList" ng-click="locate.addressListClick($index);">
      {{ list.formatted_address }}
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div> <!-- /result tab -->
  </div><!-- /tab-content -->
      </div><!-- /tabbable -->
    </div><!-- /col -->
  </div><!-- /row -->
</div><!-- /container -->
```

When I want the text box to be on the side of these tabs but they for some reason keep on going below the tabs. How could I fix this.

Answer (score 11):

**Follow bootstrap grid structure.**

For more details you can refer  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="TABBEDLOCATEPANEL" ng-show="locate.toggleCheck()" class="container">
<div id=locatePanel class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="tabs-left">
            <ul id=locateTabs class="nav form-tabs nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="active" title="Locate By Address">
                    <a data-toggle="pill" href="#locateTab1" target='_self'><img src="images/Address.png" height="30" width="30"></a>
                </li>
                <li title="Locate By Existing Record">
                    <a data-toggle="pill" href="#locateTab2" target='_self'><img src="images/entity.png" height="30" width="30"></a>
                </li>
                <li title="Locate By Coordinate">
                    <a data-toggle="pill" href="#locateTab3" target='_self'><img src="images/coordinator.png" height="30" width="30"></a>
                </li>
                <li title="Geography" ng-show="locate.getJSON().geographyTab" ng-click="locate.showGeographyData();">
                    <a data-toggle="pill" href="#locateTab4" target='_self'><img src="images/geography.png" height="30" width="30"></a>
                </li>
                <li title="Results" id="ltab5" ng-show="locate.resultsTab">
                    <a data-toggle="pill" href="#locateTab5" target='_self'><img src="images/Result.png" height="30" width="30"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="locateTab1" class="tab-pane active">
                <table id=locateAddress style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 5px;">
                    <div class="field-container">
                        <input type='text' class="field" name=locatebyaddress_address ng-model="locate.locatebyaddress_address" required placeholder="Address" init-from-form>
                        <label class="floating-label">Address:</label>
                        <div class="field-underline"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-container">
                        <input type='text' class="field" name=locatebyaddress_city ng-model="locate.locatebyaddress_city" required placeholder="City" init-from-form>
                        <label class="floating-label">City:</label>
                        <div class="field-underline"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-container">
                        <input type='text' class="field" name=locatebyaddress_state ng-model="locate.locatebyaddress_state" required placeholder="State" init-from-form>
                        <label class="floating-label">State:</label>
                        <div class="field-underline"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-container">
                        <input type='text' class="field" name=locatebyaddress_zip ng-model="locate.locatebyaddress_zip" required placeholder="Zip" init-from-form>
                        <label class="floating-label">Zip:</label>
                        <div class="field-underline"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-container">
                        <input type='text' class="field" name=locatebyaddress_longitude disabled=disabled ng-model="locate.locatebyaddress_longitude" required placeholder="Longitude" init-from-form>
                        <label class="floating-label">Longitude:</label>
                        <div class="field-underline"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-container">
                        <input type='text' class="field" name=locatebyaddress_latitude disabled=disabled ng-model="locate.locatebyaddress_latitude" required placeholder="Latitude" init-from-form>
                        <label class="floating-label">Latitude:</label>
                        <div class="field-underline"></div>
                    </div>

                </table>
                <br>
                <input type=submit value=Find id=locateByAddress ng-click="locate.locateByAddress();">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type=button ng-click="locate.zoomToLocation();" ng-disabled="locate.entityDisabledCheck" ng-class="{'disabledButton':locate.isDisabledActive}" value="Zoom" id=zoomtolocation>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type=reset value=Cancel ng-click="locate.destroyLocatePanel();" id=cancelLocate>
            </div>
            <div id="locateTab2" class="tab-pane">
                <table id=locateRecord style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 5px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Entity Type</td>
                        <td>
                            <select id=locateEntityType ng-change="locate.entityChanged();" ng-model="locate.entityType">
                                <option></option>
                                <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in locate.getJSON().dropdown" value="{{key}}">{{ value }}</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Record Number</td>
                        <td>
                            <input id=recordNumberExistingRecord ng-model="locate.recordNumber" type=text name=recordNumber>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br>
                <input type=submit value=Find id=locateByExistingRecord ng-click="locate.getLocationByEntity();">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type=button ng-click="locate.zoomToLocation();" ng-disabled="locate.entityDisabledCheck" ng-class="{'disabledButton':locate.isDisabledActive}" value="Zoom" id=zoomtolocation> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type=reset value=Cancel ng-click="locate.destroyLocatePanel();" id=cancelLocate>
            </div>
            <div id="locateTab3" class="tab-pane">
                <table id=locateCoordinates style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 5px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Longitude</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type=text ng-model=locate.locateByCoordinatelongitude>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Latitude</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type=text ng-model=locate.locateByCoordinatelatitude>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type=button ng-click="locate.pickCoordinate();" id=coordinatePick name=locatePick value=PICK>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br>
                <input type=submit value=Find id=locateByCoordinate ng-click="locate.locateByCoordinate();">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type=button ng-click="locate.zoomToLocation();" ng-disabled="locate.entityDisabledCheck" ng-class="{'disabledButton':locate.isDisabledActive}" value="Zoom" id=zoomtolocation> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type=reset value=Cancel ng-click="locate.destroyLocatePanel();" id=cancelLocate>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type=button ng-click="locate.streetView();" ng-show="locate.streetViewCheck" value="Street View" id=streetView>
            </div>
            <div id="locateTab4" class="tab-pane" ng-show="locate.getJSON().geographyTab">
                <div ng-html-compile="locate.getGeographyHTML()" | trust></div>
            </div>
            <div id="locateTab5" class="tab-pane" ng-show="locate.resultsTab">
                <ul class="listAddress">
                    <li ng-repeat="list in locate.addressList" ng-click="locate.addressListClick($index);">
                        {{ list.formatted_address }}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /result tab -->
        </div>
        <!-- /tab-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /tabbable -->
</div>
<!-- /col -->
</div>
<!-- /row -->
</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could solve that by using the bootstrap grid system.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-2hfp1SzUoho7/TsGGGDaFdsuuDL0LX2hnUp6VkX3CUQ2K4K+xjboZdsXyp4oUHZj" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <a data-toggle="pill" href="#locateTab1" target='_self'><img src="images/Address.png" height="30" width="30"></img>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    Address
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <input type=text name=locatebyaddress_address ng-model="locate.locatebyaddress_address">
                </div>
            </div>
      <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <a data-toggle="pill" href="#locateTab1" target='_self'><img src="images/Address.png" height="30" width="30"></img>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    Address
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <input type=text name=locatebyaddress_address ng-model="locate.locatebyaddress_address">
                </div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpgNgp

Answer (score 2):

TRY THIS. I put a inline style into ul tab `<ul id=locateTabs class="nav form-tabs nav-pills nav-stacked" style="float: left;">`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="TABBEDLOCATEPANEL" ng-show="locate.toggleCheck()" class="container">
  <div id=locatePanel class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3">
      <div class="tabs-left">
        <ul id=locateTabs class="nav form-tabs nav-pills nav-stacked" style="float: left;">
      <li class="active" title="Locate By Address"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#locateTab1" target='_self'><img src="images/Address.png" height="30" width="30"></img></a></li>
      <li title="Locate By Existing Record"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#locateTab2" target='_self'><img src="images/entity.png" height="30" width="30"></img></a></li>
      <li title="Locate By Coordinate"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#locateTab3" target='_self'><img src="images/coordinator.png" height="30" width="30"></img></a></li>
      <li title="Geography" ng-show="locate.getJSON().geographyTab" ng-click="locate.showGeographyData();"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#locateTab4" target='_self'><img src="images/geography.png" height="30" width="30"></img></a></li>
      <li title="Results" id="ltab5" ng-show="locate.resultsTab"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#locateTab5" target='_self'><img src="images/Result.png" height="30" width="30"></img></a></li>
  </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
         <div id="locateTab1" class="tab-pane active">
    <table id=locateAddress style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 5px;">
     <div class="field-container">
                 <input type='text' class="field" name=locatebyaddress_address ng-model="locate.locatebyaddress_address" required placeholder="Address"  init-from-form>
     <label class="floating-label">Address:</label>
           <div class="field-underline"></div>
        </div>
         <div class="field-container">
                 <input type='text' class="field" name=locatebyaddress_city ng-model="locate.locatebyaddress_city" required placeholder="City" init-from-form>
     <label class="floating-label">City:</label>
           <div class="field-underline"></div>
        </div>
         <div class="field-container">
                 <input type='text' class="field" name=locatebyaddress_state ng-model="locate.locatebyaddress_state" required placeholder="State"  init-from-form>
     <label class="floating-label">State:</label>
           <div class="field-underline"></div>
        </div>
         <div class="field-container">
                 <input type='text' class="field" name=locatebyaddress_zip ng-model="locate.locatebyaddress_zip" required placeholder="Zip" init-from-form>
     <label class="floating-label">Zip:</label>
           <div class="field-underline"></div>
        </div>
         <div class="field-container">
                 <input type='text' class="field" name=locatebyaddress_longitude disabled=disabled ng-model="locate.locatebyaddress_longitude" required placeholder="Longitude"  init-from-form>
     <label class="floating-label">Longitude:</label>
           <div class="field-underline"></div>
        </div>
         <div class="field-container">
                 <input type='text' class="field" name=locatebyaddress_latitude disabled=disabled ng-model="locate.locatebyaddress_latitude" required placeholder="Latitude"  init-from-form>
     <label class="floating-label">Latitude:</label>
           <div class="field-underline"></div>
        </div>
     
    </table>
    <br>
    <input type=submit value=Find id=locateByAddress ng-click="locate.locateByAddress();"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type=button ng-click="locate.zoomToLocation();" ng-disabled="locate.entityDisabledCheck" ng-class="{'disabledButton':locate.isDisabledActive}" value="Zoom" id=zoomtolocation></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type=reset value=Cancel ng-click="locate.destroyLocatePanel();" id=cancelLocate></input>
   </div>
   <div id="locateTab2" class="tab-pane">
    <table id=locateRecord style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 5px;">
     <tr>
      <td>Entity Type</td>
      <td>
       <select id=locateEntityType ng-change="locate.entityChanged();"  ng-model="locate.entityType">
        <option></option>
        <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in locate.getJSON().dropdown" value="{{key}}">{{ value }}</option>
       </select> 
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td>Record Number</td><td><input id=recordNumberExistingRecord ng-model="locate.recordNumber" type=text name=recordNumber></td></tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <input type=submit value=Find id=locateByExistingRecord ng-click="locate.getLocationByEntity();"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type=button ng-click="locate.zoomToLocation();" ng-disabled="locate.entityDisabledCheck" ng-class="{'disabledButton':locate.isDisabledActive}" value="Zoom" id=zoomtolocation></input>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=reset value=Cancel ng-click="locate.destroyLocatePanel();" id=cancelLocate></input>
   </div>
   <div id="locateTab3" class="tab-pane">
    <table id=locateCoordinates style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 5px;">
     <tr><td>Longitude</td><td><input type=text ng-model=locate.locateByCoordinatelongitude></td></tr>
     <tr><td>Latitude</td><td><input type=text ng-model=locate.locateByCoordinatelatitude></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td><td><input type=button ng-click="locate.pickCoordinate();" id=coordinatePick name=locatePick value=PICK></td></tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <input type=submit value=Find id=locateByCoordinate ng-click="locate.locateByCoordinate();"></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type=button ng-click="locate.zoomToLocation();" ng-disabled="locate.entityDisabledCheck" ng-class="{'disabledButton':locate.isDisabledActive}" value="Zoom" id=zoomtolocation></input>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=reset value=Cancel ng-click="locate.destroyLocatePanel();" id=cancelLocate></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type=button ng-click="locate.streetView();" ng-show="locate.streetViewCheck" value="Street View" id=streetView></input>
   </div>
   <div id="locateTab4" class="tab-pane" ng-show="locate.getJSON().geographyTab">
    <div ng-html-compile="locate.getGeographyHTML()" | trust></div>
   </div>
   <div id="locateTab5" class="tab-pane" ng-show="locate.resultsTab">
    <ul class="listAddress">
     <li ng-repeat="list in locate.addressList" ng-click="locate.addressListClick($index);">
      {{ list.formatted_address }}
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div> <!-- /result tab -->
  </div><!-- /tab-content -->
      </div><!-- /tabbable -->
    </div><!-- /col -->
  </div><!-- /row -->
</div><!-- /container -->
```